# Python/Tweepy UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, twitter, encoding, utf-8, tweepy

I am trying to scrape through Twitter bios using the Twitter API with Python.

However I get this error:

> newFile.writerow(info)
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't
>   encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

I assume this occurs when someone has an emoji in their bio or screen name, however none of the following solutions seem to stop the error:

- .encode('unicode_escape')
- .encode('UTF8')
- .encode('UTF-8')

Here is the current code

```
for follower in followers.items():
    info=[]
    name =follower.name.encode('unicode_escape')
    screen_name = follower.screen_name.encode('unicode_escape')

    userId = userId + 1

    #add values to array
    values.append(userId)
    values.append(name)
    values.append(screen_name)

    csvFile = open('followers.csv','a')
    newFile =csv.writer(csvFile) #imported csv
    #add list of headers as a new row
    newFile.writerow(info)
    #close file
    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: I get: "TypeError: 'ignore' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Try `.encode('utf-8', errors = 'ignore')` @auto

Comment: "newFile.writerow(info)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)"

Should I be adding these somewhere else? I'm only adding them after the bio description, user name and name. Nothing else seems to make sense.

Comment: My workaround is to use Try/Except, leaving the row blank and counting the number of times this happens and printing the row in the IDE. Turns out the issue is not emoticon, but arabic text.

Comment: Do any of the bios or screen names have any characters from Chinese or Japanese? From my experience this will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

A major problem is that Python's CSV module is not Unicode safe - See the warnings in https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

The work around, as you've found is to encode all values to UTF-8 first:

```
name = follower.name.encode('UTF-8')
screen_name = follower.screen_name.encode('UTF-8')
```

The problem you're hitting now is Python is still trying to encode your values to ASCII. This is due to the way you've opened the file for writing. Add `b` for binary writing:

```
csvFile = open('followers.csv','ab')
```

In its complete form:

```
for follower in followers.items():
info=[]
name = follower.name.encode('UTF-8')
screen_name = follower.screen_name.encode('UTF-8')

userId = userId + 1

#add values to array
values.append(userId)
values.append(name)
values.append(screen_name)

csvFile = open('followers.csv','ab')
newFile =csv.writer(csvFile) #imported csv
#add list of headers as a new row
newFile.writerow(info)
#close file
csvFile.close()
```